# Instagram API: Invalid Platform App when fetching access token

Tags: node.js, instagram-api

I'm trying to log in using Instagram Basic Display API.

I'm trying to get the `access_token`, and I'm using axios:

```
const { code } = queryParams;
      const url = `https://instagram.com/oauth/access_token`;
      const result = await axios.request({
        url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          'client_id': INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
          'client_secret': INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET,
          'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
          'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost:3000/auth/instagram/token',
          code,
        },
      });
```

I'm getting a `400` error, with the message `invalid platform app`. All the values sent exist and are correct.

My `redirect_uri` doesn't exist though, but it's added to the authorized URL list. It doesn't exist because I don't have https in my local server.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. [The official example given by Instagram](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions#step-2--exchange-the-code-for-a-token) using curl uses the `-F` tag, which means that they are posting the data as the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type.

Every other post format I tried is ignored. Changing your code to post as a form and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019404/invalid-platform-app-error-using-instagram-basic-display-api)

> const querystring = require('querystring');
>
> //Make Object with params const data = {
> client_id: 'xxxxxxx',
> client_secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
> grant_type: 'authorization_code',
> redirect_uri: 'https://example.com/auth',
> code: 'xxxx' }
>
> //Make the Call
> axios.post("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
> querystring.stringify(data)) .then(function (response) {
> console.log("OK", response.data);  })  .catch(function (error) {
> console.log(error);  });